# Split a string by 2 various number of chars, skipping non alphanumerics

Tags: ruby

I have a string like:

```
hn$8m3kj4.23hs@8;
```

i need to split it as follow: first entry should be of one char length, second entry of 2 chars, third entry of one char, fourth - by 2 chars and so on.

then concatenate one char with two chars entries by a semicolon `:`

if some chars at the end remains unpaired, they should be displayed as well.

it is important to skip all non alphanumeric chars.

so the final string should be:

```
h:n8 m:3k j:42 3:hs 8:
```

see, 8 has no 2 chars pair but it is displayed anyway.

i have tried with a loop but i get huge code.
also tried regexs but it split by wrong number of chars.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried.

Comment: nope, sorry, too ugly for public :)

Comment: What should an input string of `abcde` produce as output?

Comment: mm, are my English so bad? :) it should produce: `a:bc d: e:`, cause `d` and `e` are "unpaired", `abcdef` instead should produce `a:bc d:ef`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your English. However, it wasn't clear whether `d:e` or `d: e:` was your desired goal. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 s = "hn$8m3kj4.23hs@8;"

 s.gsub(/\W/, '').scan(/(.)(..)?/).map { |i| i.join ':' }.join ' '
 => "h:n8 m:3k j:42 3:hs 8:"
```

this will not skip underscores though.

if you need to skip them as well, use this one:

```
s = "hn$8m3k_j4.23hs@8;_"

s.gsub(/\W|_/, '').scan(/(.)(..)?/).map { |i| i.join ':' }.join ' '
=> "h:n8 m:3k j:42 3:hs 8:"
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=split-a-string-by-2-various-number-of-chars-skipping-non-alphanumerics.rb&run=true)

Comment: This will fail if the string contains dashes. You may want to edit the gsub to specifically reject non-alphanumerics.

Comment: @MarkThomas, not sure why you think so, it actually does reject non alphanums by `\W`. added a new test with dashes and of course it pass just well. see the link above

Comment: Sorry, I meant underscore. `\W` rejects non-*word* characters, and an underscore is considered a word character.

Comment: mm, differs a lot from my loops trying :) no interpolations and fitted in a single short line. thank you.